# Python - Selenium Fail

Tags: python, html

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

chromedriver = 'C:\chromedriver.exe'
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
```

I tried running this in CMD, and I get the following error:

[image: Error message]

Comment: I fixed it, but now it tries username = selenium.find_element_by_id("username"), and says selenium is not defined.

Comment: You want `browser.find_element_by_id`. Also when you update your question edit in the new code.

Comment: Chromedisk error: There is no disk in the drive. Please insert a disk into drive E:

Comment: Wat. Did you refer to E: anywhere?

Comment: No, I don't think so.

Comment: Please post error messages as text, not screenshots, so that they can be found when someone searches for them.

Comment: There is no disk in the drive, please inset a disk into drive E:.
Cancel  |  Try Again  |  Continue